# Does a Berry phase operator exist?

Tags: operators, berry-pancharatnam-phase

The closed-path Berry phase can have measurable effects and, if I am understanding correctly, is a measurable quantity in and of itself. If that is so, is there a Hermitian operator with Berry phases as its eigenvalues? What would it be, and what would its eigenstates be?

Comment: What is this operator supposed to act on? The Berry phase is a property of a specific trajectory through the space of states (in the Schrödinger picture), but ordinary observables in the Schrödinger picture act on single states, not trajectories.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't know. The reason I'm asking is that in my introductory QM course (but I believe in any such course), I was taught that observables are represented by Hermitian operators and wanted to know if actually this is not always the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single operator corresponding to the Berry phase because the Berry phase is not a property of a single quantum state, but of a full *trajectory* through state space. "Observables are Hermitian operators" does not mean "anything you can measure is a Hermitian operator", it means *measurable properties of states are Hermitian operators acting on those states*.

It easy to construct plenty of other things you can "observe" that are not actually observables/Hermitian operators, e.g. if you do repeated measurements on an identically realized state, you can compute (an approximation for) the standard deviation of the observable being measured, but the standard deviation itself is not a linear operator on states, either.